# AngularJS authentication questions

Tags: angularjs, rest, authentication

We are planning to implement an AngularJS web application communicating with Business components via REST service layer. The web app needs to offer authentication mechanism.
For example we are particularly concerned by the user authentication process since Angular code is practically available to the users on their clients.

And how can we reassure that the users are authenticated after the initial authentication process (in JSP/PHP we would use sessions)?

Could you please give us some pros. and cons?

Comment: Could you show us what you have tried?

Comment: At the moment we are making experiments with JWT (Json Web Token) authentication concept, but we are wondered if there might be some other better and more secure options...?

Answer (score 0):

Your right client side code is available, viewable, and editable thru standard browser developer tools. If your company does any type of security audits on your software you'll find that for security reasons processing is done on server side outside of the view of the client code. The companies I have worked for have taken the approach to trust nothing that is sent from the client side to the server.

On the server side the REST layer typically contains a authentication layer that will bubble back to the client when.

-invalid session 
-incorrect permissions to make rest call
-invalid REST args 
-prevents script jacking into text fields
-etc...

Answer (score 0):

1. When working with angular or other client side only applications, I recommend using Token based authentication.
2. A demo application in Angularjs 
   [Token Based Application](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/token-based-authentication-with-angularjs-nodejs--cms-22543)

[Angular JS, Web API Token Based Authentication](http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/09/angularjs-token-authentication-using-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/)